SLDS Email Docked Composer not displaying complete composer
We are creating a create send email component which is replica of standard email component due to customer requirement. So created a custom button at LWC component, On click of the button email composer (Docked Composer) need to display. But the email composer does not show clearly some of the parts are hidden and some of the parts are overriding. We tried to different scenarios, email composer not working clearly.
Please respond if anyone face the same kind of issue.
Regards.
Ragavendra Kolli
Please find the attached images

